# Fully justified LTR paragraphs in XePersian

Tags: horizontal-alignment, bidi, xepersian

I am using XePersian to write a report in Persian, which must include an English abstract at the end. I currently use `\lr{}` for each paragraph:

```
\flushleft

\begin{abstract}
 \lr{Abstract in English - 1st paragraph.}

 \lr{Abstract in English - 2nd paragraph.}

 \lr{Abstract in English - 3rd paragraph.}
\end{abstract}
```

The problem is that if I don't use `\flushleft`, everything will be right-aligned and if I do use it, the paragraphs won't be fully justified.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why not `\begin{latin}`  `\end{latin}` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *salim bou* mentioned in the comments, I should have used `\begin{latin}` `\end{latin}`:

```
\begin{latin} 
 \begin{abstract}
  Abstract in English - 1st paragraph.

  Abstract in English - 2nd paragraph.

  Abstract in English - 3rd paragraph.
 \end{abstract}
\end{latin}
```